# How smart is SQLite.Net when using Linq?

Tags: c#, sqlite

When using SQLite.Net the Linq queries are turned into hopefully performant SQL queries. 
Is there however a chance that some sort of query is too complex and leads to a full and slow table scan? Like, let's say I want to get one item from a table with 50k rows - I don't want it to loop all rows and compare the values against my requested value in .Net code; it should generate a proper "where" clause. 
I know that one can see the queries generated by SQLite.Net but as they are dynamic there is no guarantee that a stupid combination of clauses might lead to slow performance. 
Or am I thinking too far and this cannot happen?

Comment: I 'm not sure what the question is. Are you asking if the generated SQL is always the most performant version possible?

Comment: Yes, you're thinking too far and suffering from analysis paralysis. Build and get users using your code. There seem to be a lot of people using SQLite.Net judging from the github page so there probably aren't any serious performance bugs.

Comment: @Jon The question is: is everything I build by using Linq translated into SQL queries (performant or not) or is there a chance that the scanning is performed by Sqlite.Net itself (in code) after retrieving/looping _all_ rows of a table.